# How can I check what redis port and instance sidekiq is connected to?

Tags: ruby, redis, sidekiq

I'm working with sidekiq and redis. I'm trying to find out and debug some issues but for that, I'd like to know what URL sidekiq is connecting to. I know i can check it in the file where i set my server and client, but is there a function I can use  ala `Resque.redis` that will show what redis instance sidekiq is connected to?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The URL info is shown at the bottom of the Web UI.  Or you can use this code snippet:

```
Sidekiq.redis { |c| p c.client.location }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much Mike. I knew the url was display on the web, but I didn't wanna have to go through the web panel each time.

Comment: Does this guarantee that my Rails is success connected to redis?

Comment: Sidekiq 7.1.1: `Sidekiq.redis {|r| puts r.config.server_url }`

Answer (score 5):

With recent versions of Sidekiq, you need to use:

`Sidekiq.redis { |conn| p conn.connection[:location] }`

If you want to get the hash with more information:

`Sidekiq.redis { |conn| p conn.connection }`

Comment: i believe this doesn't produce a URL with the password though

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, clearly not intended to be a public API.

```rb
Sidekiq.redis{ |conn| conn }._client.options[:url]
```